How to uninstall deprecated @babel plugins
I have many @babel plugins in my project that have been deprecated and need replaced. How can I uninstall the deprecated plugins when they don't appear in my package.json?
Example:
deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-property-regex instead.
deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
